# MPAndroidChart with two charts value padding

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart in order to draw two charts however when the two values are close they overlap like the picture

is there a way to solve this for example by setting padding on values on the red chart to be drawn on top of the green one?

[image]

Comment: Is this a `LineChart`?

Comment: @TylerV Yes, what i want is to show green value above red one